# How to restore a SQL Server 2005 DB from a local .BAK-file?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I need to restore a DB from a .BAK-file that is not located on the server, but on my local machine.

Normally I remote desktop to the SQL server, copy the .BAK-file, and do the restore that way with Management Studio. This feels a bit awkward though, especially on days like this, when I get thrown out because the number of allowed connections has been reached on remote desktop.

I'd like to restore the DB from a file on my local machine, with Management Studio. I can connect to SQL server via Management Studio, but when I do Tasks -> Restore -> Database and choose file, it only lets me browse the file system of the server.

Is there any way to make it look for the .BAK on my local file system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I assume this is a one time occasion and not a permanent fix*

---

Can you access your local systems drive via the server? 
e.g.

> \\yourpcnumber\c$

Otherwise why don't you just copy the file to the server?

Comment: I would set up a network device on the server so I could access my file system, but I'm not allowed to do that, and as I said, I can't connect via remote desktop to copy the file because the max number of allowed connections has been reached. More people poking around on that machine it seems.

Comment: if you can RDP to the server, you should be able to open up a share to the server to copy the file \\server\c$

Comment: ck - I actually just had the same idea myself, and started looking into it. And I feel a bit embarrassed now that I didn't look this up before posting a question here. ;)

Comment: ck - well, that solved it. It doesn't answer my question, but it solved the problem. Post an answer to this thread so I at least can give you an up vote on it.

Comment: That's what I meant with the "why don't you just copy the file to the server" part... ;-) But probably that was not clear enough.

Comment: Zaagmans - Yes, I got that after pondering for a while, and that's why you got the answered-tag. Should've come up with that myself, but sometimes you brain just locks up. ;) And to make the day even more interesting, the back up was corrupt! Yay!

Comment: Ouch! I hope not everything has been lost now?! Good luck! ;-)